# How do you shut down threads after running test in the sbt shell

Tags: scala, sbt

I am using sbt 0.13.9 with scalatest. The project contains a bunch of daemon threads. Simplified example:

```
object Storage {
  private lazy val scheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor(
    new com.twitter.concurrent.NamedPoolThreadFactoryNamedPoolThreadFactory("thread-name", true)
  )

  scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable {
    override def run(): Unit = {
      println("Running ...")
      // do something
    }
  }, 0, 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)

  // other code
}
```

Some tests use `Storage`. When running `test` in the SBT shell, I can see that the `Runnable` is still running after all tests have finished.

```
[info] All tests passed.
[success] Total time: 32 s, completed Dec 1, 2015 10:39:57 AM
> 2015-12-01 10:40:51,806 INFO  Storage$$anon$1 - Running ...
2015-12-01 10:41:51,810 INFO  Storage$$anon$1 - Running ...
```

How can I make sure that they are stopped?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like daemon threadFactory is used for creating `Runnable` tasks, but scheduler itself is executed on normal/non daemon thread pool.

As an option.
After scheduling  your task , you should take `ScheduleFuture` and handle it. For example `cancel` after some executions.

```
val fff = scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable {
    override def run(): Unit = {
      println("Running ...")
      // do something
    }
  }, 0, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)


  fff.cancel(true)
```

Comment: Thats already done in `NamedPoolThreadFactory` if you send `true` as seconds argument.

Comment: I've reviewed my answer.

Comment: The scheduler is created from the test thread. The test instantiates an object which contains the scheduler. I cannot cancel the `ScheduledFuture` as this is a recurring task.